# What is the use of the interrupt flag IRQF_TRIGGER_NONE?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

can anyone explain the flag, IRQF_TRIGGER_NONE declared linux in the file,/kernel/linux/include/interrupt.h.
How can one use this flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IRQF_TRIGGER_NONE` is defined with a bit-mask of 0 indicating that it does NOT imply any kind of edge or level triggered interrupt behaviour.

```
#define IRQF_TRIGGER_NONE       0x00000000
```

Hence registering an ISR using `request_irq()` with `IRQF_TRIGGER_NONE` does NOT modify the existing configuration of the IRQ. This is important in scenarios where we would simply like to register an ISR for an hardware in the mode it is currently configured <sup>**[[1]](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/interrupt.h#n24)**</sup>.

Example usage of [**`IRQF_TRIGGER_NONE`** in the Linux Kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=IRQF_TRIGGER_NONE).

Comment: If the flag is used to configure the ISR for its current mode, how to know the current configured mode,?

Comment: @Mike The `IRQF_TRIGGER_NONE` flag is a quick way to simply continue using the interrupt simply like it has already been setup(in boot-loader, or earlier in kernel) and register an ISR for it. Identifying the currently configured mode is usually done by reading the appropriate registers on the device in question.